# Is the sequence $\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{e^k+\sqrt{k}+1} $ convergent or divergent?

Tags: limits, riemann-sum

I have been asked to find the limit of the following sequence
$$\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{e^k+\sqrt{k}+1}$$

when $ n $ goes to infinity.
I tried to write it as a Riemann sum but the exponential term makes it quite impossible.
Any help or idea will be so appreciate.
Thanks for all.

Comment: The title is "Is this sequence convergent or divergent?".

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah: unless I am missing something $\frac{1}{e^k+\sqrt{k}+1}\leq e^{-k}$. Since the series $\sum_ke^{-k}$ converges, then so does the sequence $\sum^n_{k=0}\frac{1}{e^k+\sqrt{k}+1}$. Knowing the caliber of Mathematics you do, I think something is missing in your question.

Comment: I don't think that was the point user was making. Your title and your post are asking two different things.

Comment: @NinadMunshi Yes indeed, the answer to the title is trivially yes but find the sum in a closed form seems an harder problem.

Comment: Integral comparison could work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That the sequence converges is clear from comparison test:

$\frac{1}{e^k+\sqrt{k}+1}\leq e^{-k}$

Since the series $\sum_ke^{-k}$ converges, then so does the sequence $s_n=\sum^n_{k=1}\frac{1}{e^k+\sqrt{k}+1}$.

From the caliber of mathematics you do, I think that that may not be what you intended to ask.  As for the value of the limit, I ignore whether there is closed form or an exact integral representation.

I think that a numerical computation is in place. I wrote a simple R script to estimate the first 30 elements of the sequence at double precision.

```
myfun <- function(x){   1/(1+ exp(x)+ sqrt(x)) }

options(digits=15) s <- sapply(0:30,function(x){myfun(x)})

data.frame(n=0:30,S_n=cumsum(s))
```

One of course can write simple code to obtain multiple precision, but this is just for MSE.

[image]